# Bootstrap 3 panel header with buttons wrong position

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3 and I would like to add some buttons in panel header, on top-right corner. When trying to add them, they are show below title baseline.

Code : http://bootply.com/82631

What are the missing CSS I should add either to the title, panel heading, or buttons ?

Answer (score 180):

I would start by adding `clearfix` class to the `<div>` with `panel-heading` class. Then, add both `panel-title` and `pull-left` to the `H4` tag. Then, add `padding-top`, as necessary.

Here's the complete code:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
      <h4 class="panel-title pull-left" style="padding-top: 7.5px;">Panel header</h4>
      <div class="btn-group pull-right">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">## Lock</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">## Delete</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">## Move</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

http://bootply.com/98827

Comment: This works, only problem is that Panel Header gets pulled to the top of the div and the btn-group vertically aligns

Comment: Or just remove the `.panel-title` from the `<h4>` and you won't need the padding.

Answer (score 156):

I'm a little late to the game here, but the simple answer is to move the H4 AFTER the button div. This is a common issue when floating, always have your floats defined BEFORE the rest of the contents or you'll have that extra line-break problem.

```
<div class="panel-heading">
    <div class="btn-group pull-right">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">## Lock</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">## Delete</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">## Move</a>
    </div>
    <h4>Panel header</h4>
</div>
```

The issue here is that when your floats are defined after other items, the float's top will start at the last line-position of the element immediately before it. So, if the previous item wraps to line 3, your float will start at line 3 too.

Moving the float to the TOP of the list eliminates the issue because there are no previous elements to push it down and anything after the float will be rendered at the top line (assuming there is room on the line for all items)

Example of correct and incorrect ordering and the effects:
http://www.bootply.com/HkDlNIKv9g

Comment: If you not like h4 size use <h4><small>Panel header</small></h4>

Comment: I can't figure out why my button doesn't fit inside of the panel-heading. The button is pushed down by the panel-heading's padding and doesn't increase the height of the panel-heading. What am I doing wrong? (Edit: apparently that was because of adding a class to an h4... but still now the heading is too tall.)

Comment: I had to add clearfix to panel-heading and add the padding like in the above answer. Can you make a working sample/demo?

Comment: Nate, here's a sample of correct vs incorrect ordering.
http://www.bootply.com/HkDlNIKv9g

Comment: I think that should be changed the class btn-sm with btn-xs. It fits better

Answer (score 42):

You should apply a "clearfix" to clear the parent element. Next thing, the h4 for the header title, extend all the way across the header, so after you apply clearfix, it will push down the child element causing the header div to have a larger height.

Here is a fix, just replace it with your code.

```
  <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
     <b>Panel header</b>
       <div class="btn-group pull-right">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">## Lock</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">## Delete</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">## Move</a>
      </div>
   </div>
```

*Editted on 12/22/2015 - added .clearfix to heading div*

Comment: should work if you add the clearfix class to panel-heading instead of adding another empty div

Answer (score 10):

I placed the button group inside the title, and then added a clearfix to the bottom.

```
<div class="panel-heading">
  <h4 class="panel-title">
    Panel header
    <div class="btn-group pull-right">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">## Lock</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">## Delete</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">## Move</a>
    </div>
  </h4>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: more elegant :  <div class="panel-heading clearfix">  ;)

Answer (score 8):

Try putting the `btn-group` inside the `H4` like this..

```
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h4>Panel header
    <span class="btn-group pull-right">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">## Lock</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">## Delete</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">## Move</a>
    </span>
    </h4>
</div>
```

http://bootply.com/lpXoMPup2d

Comment: No it's not "good practice", but it did answer the original question. I update the answer according to best practice.

Answer (score 6):

You are part right. with `<b>title</b>` it looks fine, but I would like to use `<h4>`.

I have put `<h4 style="display: inline;">` and it seams to work.

Now, I only need to add some vertival align.

Comment: `inline-block` is better.

Answer (score 6):

In this case you should add `.clearfix` at the end of container with floated elements.

```
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h4>Panel header</h4>
    <div class="btn-group pull-right">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">## Lock</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">## Delete</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">## Move</a>
    </div>
    <span class="clearfix"></span>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/NCXkOtIkD6

Answer (score 1):

I've found using an additional class on the .panel-heading helps.

```
<div class="panel-heading contains-buttons">
   <h3 class="panel-title">Panel Title</h3>
   <a class="btn btn-sm btn-success pull-right" href="something.html"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Create</a>
</div>
```

And then using this less code:

```
.panel-heading.contains-buttons {
    .clearfix;
    .panel-title {
        .pull-left;
        padding-top:5px;
    }
    .btn {
        .pull-right;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `h4` element is displayed as a block. Add a border to it and you'll see what's going on. If you want to float something to the right of it, you have a number of options:

1. Place the floated items *before* the block (h4) element.
2. Float the h4 element as well.
3. Display the h4 element inline.

In either case, you should add the `clearfix` class to the container element to get correct padding for your buttons.

You may also want to add the `panel-title` class to, or adjust the padding on, the h4 element.

Answer (score 0):

or this?  By using row class

```
  <div class="row"> 
  <div class="  col-lg-2  col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
     <h4>Panel header</h4>
  </div>
 <div class="  col-lg-10  col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10 ">
    <div class="btn-group  pull-right">
       <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">## Lock</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">## Delete</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">## Move</a>
    </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```