# Bootstrap buttons collapse inside the panel header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is some example code: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/7243/

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <ul class="list-unstyled pull-right list-inline">
            <li>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-default">Archive</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <img src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/avatar_2x.png" alt="..." width="80px" height="80px" class="img-circle">

<h4>John Doe</h4>

    </div>
</div>
```

The weird thing is the panel header doesn't expand to contain the buttons. I have a feeling it's to do with the float i've applied. Can anyone show me where I have gone wrong and why this is happening please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `.clearfix` class to `.panel-heading`

http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/7245/

Answer (score 1):

As answered in: [Bootstrap 3 panel header with buttons wrong position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18963881/bootstrap-3-panel-header-with-buttons-wrong-position)

> You should apply a "clearfix" to clear the parent element.

This works:

```
    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
        <ul class="list-unstyled pull-right list-inline">
            <li>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-default">Archive</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <img src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/avatar_2x.png" alt="..." width="80px" height="80px" class="img-circle">

<h4>John Doe</h4>

    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the example code: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/7248/

Answer (score 0):

First of all your structure seems incorrect.
you should start with a button and use the dropdown method for the button to open up your list.

A working sample:

[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/7251/)

And the "working code":

```
    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
        <div class="btn-group pull-right">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Action</button>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                </li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <img src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/avatar_2x.png" alt="..." width="80px" height="80px" class="img-circle">

<h4>John Doe</h4>

    </div>
</div>
```